# Sum certain rows given 2 constraints in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am trying to write an conditional statement with the following constraints. Below is an example data frame showing the problem I am running into.

```
Row <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
La <- c(51.25,51.25,51.75,53.25,53.25,54.25,54.25)
Lo <- c(128.25,127.75,127.25,119.75,119.25,118.75,118.25)
Y <- c(5,10,2,4,5,7,9)
Cl <- c("EF","EF","EF","EF","NA","NA","CE")     

d <- data.frame(Row,La,Lo,Y,Cl)

  Row    La     Lo  Y Cl
1   1 51.25 128.25  5 EF
2   2 51.25 127.75 10 EF
3   3 51.75 127.25  2 EF
4   4 53.25 119.75  4 EF
5   5 53.25 119.25  5 NA
6   6 54.25 118.75  7 NA
7   7 55.25 118.25  9 CE
```

I would like to sum column "Y" (removing all values from that row) if "Cl" is NA with the corresponding "Lo" **and** "La" values that are close (equal to or less than 1.00). In effect, I want to remove NA from being in the data frame without losing the value of "Y", but instead adding this value to its closest neighbor.

I would like the return data frame to look like this:

```
Row2 <- c(1,2,3,4,7)
La2 <- c(51.25,51.25,51.75,53.25,55.25)
Lo2 <- c(128.25,127.75,127.25,119.75,118.25)
Y2 <- c(5,10,2,9,16)
Cl2 <- c("EF","EF","EF","EF","CE")     

d2 <- data.frame(Row2,La2,Lo2,Y2,Cl2)

 Row2   La2    Lo2 Y2 Cl2
1    1 51.25 128.25  5  EF
2    2 51.25 127.75 10  EF
3    3 51.75 127.25  2  EF
4    4 53.25 119.75  9  EF
5    7 55.25 118.25 16  CE
```

**recent edit:** If NA row is close to one row in terms of Lo value and same closeness to another row in La value, join by La value. If there are 2 equally close rows of Lo and La values, join by smaller La value.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What if the NA row is closer to one row in terms of Lo value and closer to another row in La value? What if there are two equally close rows of Lo and La values?

Comment: Great question! I had not thought of that possibility. If that is the case, choose to sum with closer La.

Comment: If there are 2 equally close values, sum to lower value La.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method to use if you can make some distance matrix `m` for the distance between all the (La, Lo) rows in your data. I use the output of `dist`, which is euclidean distance. The row with the lowest distance is selected, or the earliest such row if the lowest distance is shared by > 1 row.

```
w <- which(is.na(d$Cl))
m <- as.matrix(dist(d[c('La', 'Lo')]))
m[row(m) %in% w] <- NA
d$g <- replace(seq(nrow(d)), w, apply(m[,w], 2, which.min))

library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  summarise(La = La[!is.na(Cl)],
            Lo = Lo[!is.na(Cl)],
            Y = sum(Y), 
            Cl = Cl[!is.na(Cl)]) %>% 
  select(-g)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      La    Lo     Y Cl   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
# 1  51.2  128.     5 EF   
# 2  51.2  128.    10 EF   
# 3  51.8  127.     2 EF   
# 4  53.2  120.     9 EF   
# 5  54.2  118.    16 CE
```

Comment: I guess you can also do this with `distm` `i1 <- d$Cl != "NA";library(geosphere);m1 <- distm(d[!i1, c("Lo", "La")], d[i1, c("Lo", "La")])`

Comment: Yes it's probably better to use `distm` if these are geo-coordinates, and the `i1` indexing within the `dist`/`distm` would also be more efficient than computing the full distance matrix as in this answer.

Comment: I was working on it, then I found your answer.  So, it is almost similar.  You can add it

Comment: Yes, I just tried running code of @IceCreamToucan and my computer will not compute dist given the size of my data frame

Comment: These are geo-coordinates calculating yields within certain world climates